# Flink :Purging Process Window function Data

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I need to have aggregation window in flink.
I can't use aggregate function. since the getResult calculation requires me state access.
So I tried to use aggregate with process :

```
   .aggregate( 
    new AggregateFunction<Entry, Double, Double>() {
                       ...........
                    };
            , new ProcessWindowFunction<Double,Result,Entry,TimeWindow>() {

                @Override
                public void process(Entry item,
                        ProcessWindowFunction<Double, Result, Entry, TimeWindow>.Context ctx,
                        Iterable<Double> aggInput, Collector<Result> output) throws Exception {


                }

    }
```

But still , I need just the latest value of the aggInput , and I don't see a reason to save thos in memory, in my app it can be milliards of data. so I thought if I can purge each time the window data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you combine an `AggregateFunction` with a `ProcessWindowFunction`, only the latest value of the aggregate is kept in the window state, and the Iterable sent to the process method will only contain that one pre-aggregated entry. (A `ReduceFunction` will work the same way.)

In other words, the optimization you are looking for is already there. The [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#useful-state-size-considerations) has a bit more detail.